# Automate excel with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel

I have a very large excel spreadsheet which i send to my clients to make changes to their products and they mark the changes. When the spreadsheet comes back I have to verify the changes with my master sheet. There is a unique code for a product but a new product is marked new until i allocate the code. I do this in excel because my clients are comfortable with excel. 
I am looking for a way to automate this whole process, but don't know where to start. I am using Visual studio Ultimate 2010 and have SQL Server Standard Edition. 
is it possible to have an application that grabs reads the excel and puts it in database and checks or verifies as it does so. Then allocates primary keys and generates a report?

Comment: Since the data resides in a database have you given thought to sending them the data in some sort of serialized form (or even in an Access database) and then write a small C# Win Forms application that would allow your customers to edit the data. Then they just send you the edited data which you can import into your master database.

Comment: @mark-kram The data is in excel spreadsheet. My clients want data sent in a spreadsheet. Any other format they are not comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check out [Automating Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178745%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from the MSDN library.  That will get you started with the Excel side.  Then just work with the database in a standard console application and import.

Comment: When you say in a console application  you mean command line input only? what is the advantage over GUI? i was thinking of having a win form.

Comment: If you are just importing from a file, it doesn't matter if it is a GUI or command line.  GUI will be easier to pick a specific file for import, but you could always just put the file in a directory that you receive from you clients and import from all Excel files from a specific directory.

Comment: Thats my plans as well. how do you handle blank cells where there is no primary key. this will be either a new product or just cell left blank.

Comment: I would add logic to whatever application you create to check for the blank cell.  Then, either create one in code, or let the database create one for you, if the cell is destined for an auto generated column.

Comment: I see what you mean. Will work at tonight and see how it goes.i will start by the importing part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work in C#, use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library. You can import a reference if you have excel installed. [This](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) might be of use. For the database part, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about converting the Excel spreadsheet into XML on your end and then move the data into you database, take a look at this [LINK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380) and this [LINK](http://www.sharpprogrammer.com/dotnet/how-to-read-excel-file-in-c-net/) and this [LINK](http://c-sharp-paradise.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-convert-excel-to-xml-in-cnet.html) too.

Comment: i once converted excel to xml. It was a bigger file than my original excel file. Whats the benefit of having it as xml than excel?

Comment: You can now de-serialize the data into a C# WinForms app, process the data and then serialize it into you database without having to do anything manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea and not a full developed solution, but you can use OleDb to reach your excel file and read its contents like it was a database table.
Then it's up to you to connect to your main database (SqlServer) and apply the logic required to 'merge' one data source into the other one

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();    
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp\test.xls;" + 
              "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;'";

using(OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    c.Open();
    string selectString = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
    using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(selectString))
    {
        cmd1.Connection = c;
        using (OleDbDataReader myReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
        {
            myTable.Load(myReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all your data from the first excel sheet file is loaded in memory inside a datatable object

Comment: I have done this code before. the challenge is the excel i receive likely contains  data that needs to verified. Putting it in a data table before populating is a great idea. However it would be good to filter it in excel. is it possible that when it reads it looks for particular values and blanks ( for new products) and puts it in a data table. that way I have almost half of my work done.

Comment: Not sure if I get it, but, once you have an OleDbDataReader, you could loop on the excel rows one by one and check the values coming from excel before inserting the row in a datatable.